# Understanding how Script Component Updates Data in DB

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am very new to scripting in SSIS, and simply need to use it to update values in an existing table.

Perhaps I'm taking the wrong approach because I'm finding very few examples where the Script Component is used for this purpose.  If there is a better approach to updating data within SQL Server, on a schedule, using elaborate business logic, I'd prefer to use the standard approach.

But in regard to Script Component, I've seen examples where columns are added, but none where values are simply updated.

So far I've created this test script to perform the simplest operation possible:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    Row.AutoModel = "123";
}
```

I run the SSIS package.  I know it runs this method because I placed a breakpoint there.  After the SSIS package finishes successfully, I expected all the AutoModel fields to become "123" within the DB, but nothing has changed.  Is there something else I need to do to invoke these updates?

Comment: Are you _updating_ data, or creating it? Use a Destination component for the latter.

Comment: I just want to update.  If I have to create a column, I'll try that, but I would like to know why update isn't working.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using the script component and not the Execute SQL component?

Comment: I am using a combination of SQL and C#, but expect the business logic would be easier to perform in C# rather than SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSIS has two different scripting items, which can be a bit confusing. The Script Task appears in the toolbox for the Control Flow design tab, and the Script Component appears in the toolbox for the Data Flow tab.

In this case, you are using the Script Component, which is a data flow transformation.

A data flow typically has a data source, one or more transformations, and a data destination. You want to update records in the database, rather than insert them, so you need an OLE DB Command at the end of your data flow, which invokes a stored procedure.

You’ll write the stored procedure to perform the required update, and it takes the necessary parameters. The OLE DB Command object should be configured to map fields in the data flow to the parameters of the stored procedure.

You say “perhaps I’m taking the wrong approach”. In my experience, the Script Component can be  useful, but is best used sparingly. Maybe quite a lot of your processing can be handled by standard components (eg table lookups, conditional splits, derived columns, and aggregations)?

Using SSIS that way gives big advantages. It gives best performance. It is quicker to develop and maintain. When you run the package, you can see which paths your data is flowing down. You can attach a data viewer to examine the data.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  I didn't realize I needed to write my own SQL command and kept trying to use the Destination Assistant instead of OLE DB Command.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad that helped. It's not exactly obvious. I've been using SSIS a lot recently and I think it's a brilliant tool.